# SONAR analysis from parent directory

Tags: ant, sonarqube, jacoco

I have a simple question, yet I don't have an answer. Can some one pls help:

What I have is:

1. ParentDirectory

   - Child_module1

     - Child_module2

I'm analyzing using sonar ant.

```
<property name="sonar.sources" value="/xyz/home/emahaboo/work/abc_project_branch/ParentDirectory"/>
<property name="sonar.binaries" value="/xyz/home/emahaboo/work/abc_project_branch/ParentDirectory"/>
```

I'm able to connect to the sonar server and get the integration test coverage for 1 module. Like this

```
<property name="sonar.sources" value="xyz/ParentDirectory/childModule1"/>
<property name="sonar.binaries" value="/xyz/ParentDirectory/childModule1"/>
```

There are "n" number of modules. I wanted to know how to run the following:
 1. Run analysis for more than 1 module. like this

```
xyz/ParentDirectory/ChildModule1
 xyz/ParentDirectory/ChildModule2
```

2.Run analysis from the ParentDirectory
 xyz/ParentDirectory/

Issues I am facing:
For 1: I see SONAR analyses on `ChildModule2`
For 2: I get this error: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to get the canonical path of xyz/ParentDirectory/ / / / / /`

Can some one please help?

Really apprecite it

Answer (score 0):

The Sonar documentation describes how multi-module builds are configured in ANT:

- [Multi-module documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Ant+Task#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeAntTask-Multi-moduleProject)

It also provides links to two examples:

1. [java-ant-modules-same-structure](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/multi-module/ant/java-ant-modules-same-structure)
2. [java-ant-modules-different-structures](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/multi-module/ant/java-ant-modules-different-structures)